# Java HttpURLConnection how to receive multiple responses from server

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I am attempting to connect to a server with a POST message asking the server to subscribe me. The server will then hold the http connection open and send back asynchronous messages to me with live statuses until I request to cancel the subscription or close the connection myself. I am having trouble reading these subsequent responses from the server. The below code does connect to the server and read the first response successfully and print it to the console. The problem is after that it keeps reading the same response (the first response) over infinitely and printing it to the screen.

Does anyone see what I am messing up here? I am trying to just watch for the next asynchronous message from the server and block until it comes. Also if anyone knows how to register to be notified when the next message shows up asynchronously so that I do not have to block wait that would be even better.

```
public void HttpSubscription() 
{
    byte[] result = new byte[10240];

    try
    {
        /* Generate the hard coded request data */
        final StringBuffer soap = new StringBuffer();
        soap.append("<s:Envelope><s:Body><SoapTest1>thing1</SoapTest1></s:Body></s:Envelope>");

        // to make HTTP Post request with HttpURLConnection
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.110:80/services");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        // then set some properties and make a request
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" );

        // Get a handle to the output stream 
        OutputStream OStream = conn.getOutputStream();

        // Write the soap data to the output stream
        OStream.write(soap.toString().getBytes());

        InputStream ResponseStream = conn.getInputStream();
        while (true)
        {
            int len = ResponseStream.read(result);
            String value = new String(result);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is not HTTP, it is something else. You might be able to get your server to implement it, you might not. But expecting HttpURLConnection to understand something that violates the HTTP protocol is asking a bit much, don't you think?

Comment: The server already does it the way I stated it. I did not write the server nor do I have any ability to change how it works. I agree it does not follow the Http specification regarding 1 request with 1 response; but you can use Http in this fashion. I have a client that works fine in c# already. My question is can JAVA support such an access style? Or will I have to go down to the sockets level and implement this from scratch? I would much rather just use the Http classes.

Comment: Bad luck, HttpURLConnection won't do it. You will have to go to the Socket level.

Answer (score 3):

A bit old, but I decided to correct some blatant misinformation here.

The answers stating that multiple responses for an HTTP request is not according to the HTTP specification are wrong!

From [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 10 Status Code Definitions
>
> Each Status-Code is described below, including a description of which method(s) it can follow and any metainformation required in the response.
>
> 10.1 Informational 1xx
>
> This class of status code indicates a provisional response, consisting
>   only of the Status-Line and optional headers, and is terminated by an
>   empty line. There are no required headers for this class of status
>   code. Since HTTP/1.0 did not define any 1xx status codes, servers MUST
>   NOT send a 1xx response to an HTTP/1.0 client except under
>   experimental conditions.
>
> **A client MUST be prepared to accept one or more 1xx status responses
>   prior to a regular response, even if the client does not expect a 100
>   (Continue) status message. Unexpected 1xx status responses MAY be
>   ignored by a user agent.**

Comment: For that to be useful, (1) the server responses would have to be 100-199 status and have no body, and (2) we would need evidence that `HttpURLConnection` processes those correctly. I don’t see any evidence here of either. The evidence shows that one or other is not the case.